# LPTHW Exercise15 IO Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm stuck at EX15 on learn python the hard way. Below is the code that I'm running.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv
txt = open(filename)
print 'here is your file %r' % filename
print txt.read()
print ' type the filename again'
txt_again = raw_input(">")
txt_again = open(txt_again)
print txt_again.read()
```

When I run the code on the terminal I'm getting an error stating the file or directory does not exist. I have created and saved the text document in the same folder where I have saved the python script. What could be the issue here?

[image: screen shot of the error]

Comment: If it says it's not there, it's not there. It starts at the current path or a provided full path, and won't search through every drive's directory structure looking for the right file. Also, LPTHW is bad and you should use the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 the file is in the same folder which contains the script as well.

Comment: @krishna.sjc please paste the output of `dir ex15_sample.txt`. It is quite possible that you've created a file named `ex15_sample.txt.txt` (because Windows "protects" the users from such dangerous details as file extensions by default); please also read [this](http://superuser.com/questions/295370/how-to-copy-text-in-the-windows-command-line-cmd) on how to copy-paste from `cmd.exe`; it is imperative that you add the actual text into questions, not just screenshots!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you. that exactly was the issue.